# percent calculation not working?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, percentage

Its a very interesting thing not sure why it happens but when I do:

```
(item.Count / query.Count) * 100
```

It will not give me any errors just reply with 0 and when I do:

```
(item.Count * 100) / query.Count
```

It works just fine, what am I missing here ?

Another problem I am having is formatting the output of it to string:

```
double perc = (item.Count * 100) / query.Count;
MessageBox.Show(perc.ToString("P5"));
```

Does not work gives me a huge sum like `33,333.33` or `33,000.00`, I wanted it to look like this `33.33%`, I tried several variations but for some reason it will not let me get the `.33` if I set the parenthesis to double it gets me `.00` and if I do not it doesn't give me `.33`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't multiply by 100, the [Percent Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#PFormatString) will do that for you.  Just cast to `double` when you perform the division:

```
double perc = (double)item.Count / (double)query.Count;
MessageBox.Show(perc.ToString("P5"));
```

Comment: +1 for the info was not aware of it, but there is a problem it will print `33.3333` and I want it to print `33.33` or `100.00` in resume `###.##` with the % sign.

Comment: @Guapo - The `P` specifies to display it as a percent.  The number specifies the precision.  So to display only 2 digits, use `"P2"` instead of `"P5"`, ie, `perc.ToString("P2")`.

Answer (score 5):

```
(item.Count / query.Count) * 100
```

is doing integer division and thus (item.Count / query.Count) will always evaluate to zero.  Casting as doubles prior to division will fix this.

For your formatting issue, try using String.format

ie. `string result = string.Format("string = {0:0.0%}",
        perc);`

More string formatting methods can be found here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format

Comment: @Yatrix forget useless function calls. Just do `(double)intval`

Comment: Cast is an implicit function call, so it's all preference.

Answer (score 2):

try to do (item.Count * 100d) the "d" specified that the 100 is a double. going to return you a double and also when you going to divide by query.Count

100f for float hundred

Answer (score 1):

item.Count and query.count are integers, cast them like (float)item.Count to convert them, otherwise it will do integer division and will always round down to 0.

```
((float)item.Count / (float)query.Count) * 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not casting `(item.Count / query.Count)` to a double before a division. So an int*double is 0 for some reason (at least in my code). Do `((double)item.Count / (double)query.Count)` and either change `100` to `100.0` or change it to `(double)100`. However, the later I recommend as 100 is converted to a double at runtime instead of at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `100` to `100.00`. It needs to know it's not an int
Try:

```
double perc = ((double)item.Count * 100.00) / (double)query.Count; 
MessageBox.Show(perc.ToString("P5"));
```